# Browser baixando arquivos como mime ao invés de css

Tags: php, html, css

Estou tendo problemas com uma pequena aplicação MVC PHP que estou desenvolvendo, pesquisei na internet e verifiquei que possivelmente meu `.htaccess`, segue em anexo:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Ele está correto? Pode ser em alguns das minhas libs em php também, a minha estrutura de pastas está assim:

```
|config <br/>
|-bundles.php <br/>
|-global.php <br/>
|controllers <br/>
|-index.php <br/>
|-help.php <br/>
|-home.php <br/>
|libs <br/>
|-bootstrap.php <br/>
|-controller.php <br/>
|-model.php <br/>
|-view.php <br/>
|models <br/>
|scripts <br/>
|-bootstrap.min.js <br/>
|style <br/>
|-bootstrap <br/>
|--bootstrap.min.css <br/>
|--bootstrap-theme.min.css <br/>
|-site.css <br/>
|views <br/>
|-_layout.php <-- Está pagina está carregando todas os JS's CSS's <br/>
|.htaccess <br/>
|index.php <br/>
```

Caso queira me dar uma sugestão sobre organização dos arquivos também aceito, obrigado!

PS.: Estou usando o APACHE do XAMPP

Comment: Já tentou adicionar `AddType text/css .css` no seu htaccess ? Isso normalmente acontece quando você acessa alguma url com `/` no final. Não sei se é o caso.

Comment: Como ficaria no caso? Poderia me ajudar? não conheço muito sobre .htaccess

Comment: Você vai adicionar essa linha no seu htaccess e reiniciar seu xampp.

Comment: Bom, não deu muito certo, mas fiz de uma forma pouco convencional: Criei um controller CSS para isso que contém o cabeçalho(header) do tipo text/css

Comment: Funcionou, mas será que não tem uma maneira com menos gambiarra para funcionar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48616/discussion-between-mauro-alexandre-and-marcio-eric).